# Accessing Javascript resources in a WebBrowser control (Winforms, C#)

Tags: javascript, c#, html, winforms

I've added a WebBrowser control to a WinForm using VisualStudio 2013.  I have added an HTML resource to the WinForm.

```
this.webBrowser1.DocumentText=Properties.Resources.HTMLPage1;
```

I have also added the HTML and the JavaScript to the Resources.resx file.

I press Start to debug the project and start the WinForm application and I immediately get a Script Error Message.

> Script Error An error has occurred in the script on this page.
>
> Line:0
>
> Char:0
>
> Error:Script Error
>
> Code:0
>
> URL about.require.js

It seems to me that the HTML is trying to access the scripts but can't find them.

Do I have the script in the wrong place?  As I mentioned, the HTML and the JavaScript files are in Resources.resx.

```html
<!DOCTYPE HTML>
<html>
<head>
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="chrome=1" />
    <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html;charset=utf-8" />
    <title>my project</title>
    <script src="require.js"></script>
    <script src="config.js"></script>
    <script>
        requirejs.config({
            baseUrl: 'webapp'
        });
    </script>
```

Comment: It can be possible. Try providing the full path in your src to confirm

Comment: That worked.  Thanks Dirty D.

Answer (score 0):

Sometimes it can be possible. Try providing the full path and check it again.

Also, you can make the path dynamic like
Src=".. /abc.js"

Hope that helps